# CSS - Slider alignment beside dynamic text

Tags: html, css

This is one of the most annoying things I can't seem to fix. I can't even search for it as I don't even know how to even begin to describe it to a search engine.

I have a static piece of text, a dynamic piece of text, and a slider in that order.

The dynamic piece of text displays the slide value. The problem is when the display is a single digit, the slider shifts to the left just a bit. Then when it's a double digit value, it shifts over to the right just a bit.

A picture can show this much better:

[image: Sliders being just slightly off]

My markup looks like this (though there are a couple identical fragments before and after all wrapped within a parent div):

```
<span id="triSizeGroup">
    Triangle Size: <span class="sliderDisplay" id="triSizeDisplay">12</span>
    <input id="triSizeInput" type="range" min="3" max="24" step="1" value="12" class="slider">
</span>
```

My latest attempt was trying to give the entire block a fixed width and having the slider align to the right, while the text aligns to the left. But it seems I just can't seem to figure out the magical (since logic, such as "align", "float", "position: relative", "left", "right", etc, etc, do not seem to apply here) combination of css to make this work.

I'm also not using any frameworks.

Comment: can you provide a live demo?

Comment: Have you used jquery to insert slider value in span?

Comment: Dang, I wish I could mark all of them as the answer as they all take the same route I overlooked: don't align the slider, but fix the given size of the text block. Such a simple fix; no idea why that didn't occur to me.

Comment: A live demo didn't occur to me. >.> I'll provide one in the future if only to aid finding a solution easier for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any live demo, i try just to guess what happens in your case and this is what i think should resolve your problem: simply apply a `width` css to your dynamic text which contains the current value of your slider:

```
.sliderDisplay {
  ...
  width: 1.5em; /* try using some desirable value which is high enough for a 2-digit number */
  display: inline-block; /* to respect the specified width */
}
```

Comment: Looks like your instinct is right on target. This works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `min-width` as per digit and `display:inline-block` for applying width

```
.sliderDisplay {
    min-width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `min-width` and `display: inline-block;` to **.sliderDisplay**

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
.sliderDisplay {
  min-width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span id="triSizeGroup">
    Triangle Size: <span class="sliderDisplay" id="triSizeDisplay">5</span>
<input id="triSizeInput" type="range" min="3" max="24" step="1" value="12" class="slider">
</span>
<br>
<span id="triSizeGroup">
    Triangle Size: <span class="sliderDisplay" id="triSizeDisplay">15</span>
<input id="triSizeInput" type="range" min="3" max="24" step="1" value="12" class="slider">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Used `flexbox` to achieve it

```css
#triSizeGroup {
  display: flex;
  align-itmes: center;
}

#triSizeGroup input {
margin-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<span id="triSizeGroup">
    Triangle Size: <span class="sliderDisplay" id="triSizeDisplay">12</span>
<input id="triSizeInput" type="range" min="3" max="24" step="1" value="12" class="slider">
</span>
```

Comment: This does work, though I'll admit, I'm not used to using flex for display. I guess I'll have to read up on it in the future.